# non-literal type 'compare' in a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++14

construct my own compare class for priority_queue, however, I could not figure out why the message keep showing non-literal type

And if you want to see what my code is doing, here is the description:

Merge K sorted interval lists into one sorted interval list. You need to merge overlapping intervals too.

```
class compare {
private:
    vector<vector<Interval>> tmp;
public:
    compare (vector<vector<Interval>> &intervals) {
        tmp = intervals;
    }
    bool operator() (const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b) {
        return tmp[a.first][a.second].start > tmp[b.first][b.second].start;
    }
};


class Solution {
public:
    vector<Interval> mergeKSortedIntervalLists(vector<vector<Interval>> &intervals) {
        priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, compare(intervals)> pq;

        for (int i = 0; i < intervals.size(); i++) {
            if (!intervals[i].empty()) {
                pq.push(make_pair<i, 0>);
            }
        }
        vector<Interval> res;
        while(!pq.empty()) {
            pair<int, int> node = pq.top();
            pq.pop();
            res.push_back(intervals[node.first][node.second]);
            node.second++;
            if(node.second < intervals[node.first].size()) {
                pq.push(make_pair(node.first, node.second));
            }
        }
        return mergeInterval(res);
    }

private:
    vector<Interval> mergeInterval (vector<Interval> &res) {
        if(res.empty() || res.size() == 1) return res;
        vector<Interval> ans;

        int start = res[0].start;
        int end = res[0].end;
        for (auto interval : res) {
            if(interval.start <= end) {
                end = max(interval.end, end);
            }else {
                ans.push_back({start, end});
                start = interval.start;
                end = interval.end;
            }
        }
        ans.push_back({start, end});
        return ans;
    }

};
```

error message: 
temporary of non-literal type 'compare' in a constant expression priority_queue, vector>, compare(intervals)> pq;

Comment: I can't compile this (missing definitions) and you don't say where the error is or give the exact error message.  Please read how to post a [mcve]

Comment: sorry, I did know I need to post the error message. But I was rush to post and forget it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues with the code:

1. `priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, compare(intervals)> pq;` should be
   `priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, compare> pq{compare(intervals)};`
2. `make_pair<i, 0>` should be `make_pair(i, 0)`

At least then [it compiles](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YQzVlV).

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'compare::compare()'
priority_queue, vector>, compare> pq;

This is what I get !
Confused about it.

Comment: And I add ```compare() {} in class compare```
Also
```priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, compare> pq{compare(intervals);```

And it works, I don't even know why?

Comment: could you maybe explain?

Comment: Your `compare` class has a non-default constructor. So you need to construct it yourself (`compare(intervals)`) and pass it to the queue's constructor. The parts between `<` and `>` must be types known at compile-time.